# Yii проблема с createUrl()

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет. У меня есть виджет который занимается поиском информации по базе, и выводит в нужные url. Однако у меня возникла проблема с этими url. Когда я указываю так:

```
$this->controller->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/search', array('url' => $url)));
```

То всё нормально, генерируется url такого вида

```
http://site.com/site/search?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.cc
```

А когда мне надо этот-же поиск сделать в админке(модуль admin), и код такой

```
$this->controller->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/site/search', array('url' => $url)));
```

То генерируется такой url

```
http://site.com/admin/site/search/url/http%3A%2F%2Fvk.cc
```

Т.е вместо `?url=http://vk.cc`, стало `/url/http://vk.cc`, и всё перестало работать, подскажите как это починить, и почему генерируются разные url?

URL manager:

```
        `'urlManager' => array( 'urlFormat' => 'path', `'rules' => array(` 
        `'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',` 
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', ), ),
```

Comment: Нет ли такого, что (с т.з. PHP) в методе `SiteController->actionSearch()` нет параметра `$url`, а в `Admin/SiteController->actionSearch()` - есть?

Comment: Да, везде используется один и тот-же action, я смог даже заставить работать это как надо, просто надо изменить url на такой-же как в первом случае с ?url=, вместо /url/, но как это сделать чтобы всегда так было(

Comment: @Angus123, покажите, пожалуйста, настройки CUrlManager, включая таблицу роутов

Comment: Всё стандартно

    'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),

Comment: @Angus123, первый случай подпадает под третий вариант, второй случай не подпадает ни под какой и форматируется по правилу по умолчанию.  
Попробуйте добавить следующее правило:

    
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',

Comment: Опа, чудеса! Спасибо большое :) Это помогло, и решило проблему)

Answer (score 1):

Вы решили задачу?
Может имеет смысл настроить ЧПУ?
Что-то вроде такого:

В корне создаем\переписываем `.htaccess`:

```
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        #hide index.php
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . index.php
```

---

В `config\main`:

```
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules' => array(
            // стандартное правило для обработки '/' как 'site/index'
            '' => 'site/index',
            // это пример добавления который заработал
            //'secondcontroller/<action:.*>'=>'secondcontroller/<action>',
            'user/<action:.*>'=>'user/<action>',
            //'<action:.*>'=>'site/<action>', //закомментил а то глючило с ним
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```